# Magento 1.9.3.8 - Customers as "Guest" do not appear in "Manage Customers" on back end

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, guest-checkout

If I generate an order from "logged in" accounts or "creating" an account during the check-out it all works fine, but if I check-out like "guest" the order complete with no problems and I can see it well displayed in Magento back-end even clearly stating that Customer Group is "NOT LOGGED IN", but then if I go to "Manage Customers" there is not trace about "guests" (not logged in) customers.

What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magento doesn't trace guest customers under Manage customers. You will see only registered customers records under Manage customers.

Answer (score 1):

Magento save guest customer's data as customer. It saves records as customer only for registered users.

Magento Customers tab not show customers which are related to 'NOT LOGGED IN' customer group.

If you need to show guest customer's data under Magento customer then you need to register the guest customer during checkout. There are many extension which register the guest after checkout.

You can check the following extension link which convert guest customer to registered customer:
https://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-convert-guest-checkout-customers-to-registered-customers.html

Comment: So you are telling me that basically there's no way to have a list of guests customers in Magento, right?
Of course, knowing the name of the "guest" I can filter in the "orders" list and find the customer info (inside the order), but what I was looking for was like having a filter "guests" or "not logged in" to show me all the full list right away.

Comment: Customer tables and order tables are different. You can filter the order by customer name because magento stores the name of customer(guest/registered) into order table, thats why you are able to filter those.

Comment: This could be a practical solution then?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034656/magento-display-guest-when-adding-customer-group-filter-to-order-grid

Comment: So basically you want to filter all the order by customer groups?

Comment: Not really, but that may be a solution, what I'd like, is to have the possibility to see a list of all "guests", if "guests" do not appear on "manage customers" section (for what you told me), maybe be the solution to filter all them in the order section would be fine.
P.S. The extension you suggested looks good of course, but for what I understand it converts in all aspects the "guest" to a registered customer (giving password and so on), but I want to leave the "guest" as a guest, I'm just talking about a solution for the back-end Magento view.

Comment: If you are looking to see the guest customers then you need to add one column to your order grid with customer group which filters all the guest orders.